# SetNumMapTask with a mapreduce.Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can I set the number of map task with a org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job ? The function does not seem to exist... But it exists for the org.apacache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf...

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, **setNumMapTasks** is not supported any more.

It is merely a hint to the framework(even in the old API), and doesn't guarantee that you'll get only the specified number of maps. The map creation is actually governed by the **InputFormat** you are using in your job.

You could tweak the following properties as per your needs :

- **mapred.min.split.size**
- **mapred.max.split.size**

Since you are dealing with small data, setting **mapred.max.split.size** to a lower value should do the trick. You could use **setMaxInputSplitSize(Job, long)** inside your job to alter this. The long argument is the **size of the split in bytes**, which you can set to your desired value.

Also, set the HDFS block size to a smaller value for small data using **dfs.block.size**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the case of small data but intensive computing task, it will be great to setup the number of map task. I have a look on the FileInputFormat API, it is not very clear for me to use it for handling number of map task... Can you give me a hint ?

Comment: It works great with setMaxInputSplitSize(Job, long). Thank you very much.