# clarification on Map tasks and reduce tasks in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am reading `Hadoop: The definitive guide`. During the course of understanding some of the concepts, I read a few SO posts, which made me equally confusing yet clarifying. Here are some points that I would need expert opinions on whether it is correct and what exactly happens if it not correct?

---

Lets assume this is how my HDFS looks in Psuedo-distributed cluster with one Node:

```
/local/path/to/datanode/storage/0/blk_00001  300 MB
/local/path/to/datanode/storage/0/blk_00002  300 MB
/local/path/to/datanode/storage/0/blk_00003  300 MB
/local/path/to/datanode/storage/0/blk_00004  200 MB
```

My total size of file is 1100 MB and it got split into chunks of 300 MB (which is my block size).

Now I am about to start my Mapreduce jobs:

I understand that `InputFormat` (which in turn splits the file) determines the number of maps.

**CASE 1:**

I have the following setting:
`split size mapred.min.split.size=400 MB`

There will be three MR jobs in total. Each will have a input size of 400 MB to process.

1) *Mapper 1*: That would mean the first MR job would use 300 MB from blk_00001 and 100 MB from blk_00002, (data locality is lost).

2) *Mapper 2:* Now the second mapper has to `seek` from  position 101 MB  blk_00002  + another 200 MB from blk_00003.

) *Mapper 3:* There is 100 MB left  on blk_0003 to be processed along with 200 MB from blk_0004.
Now the size is 300 MB which should be processed as whole.

**Block Size has NO ROLE in MAPRED tasks**.

**Q1:** Is everything correct till here???????

---

**CASE 2:**

Now lets say I have the following setting for my MR job:
`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=3`. This would mean for any given node, run three map tasks in parallel.

**Q2**: If all the mappers above runs parallel on same node, do they run in different Threads with similar priority or a separate process at CPU level.

---

**CASE 3**: if my `num` in `conf.setNumMapTasks(int num)` is greater than number of splits.
That is say, I have num = 10 and the number of splits = 3. The total MR job that will be executed is 3.

**Q3:**Correct??

---

**Reducer tasks:**

**Q4** A mapper has to finish before the reducer starts - in all cases to my knowledge, any examples where it will not be. because the keys need sorting and handed them in order to reducers.

**Q5** so what is the effect of `mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0.5`. This would mean when the map task is 50% complete, start the reducers. but the reducer needs map jobs to be complete. correct???

2) what is the default number of reducers if I don't specify anything.

It has been [proposed](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) to use 0.95 - 1.75 * (nodes * mapred.tasktracker.tasks.maximum). so if I have cluster with 5 nodes each with 5 cores, the formula gives (0.95 * 5 * 5) = 24 reducers .

so should I set conf.setNumReduceTasks(24)????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q1:** Is everything correct till here???????

It depends on the input format.  `FileInputFormat` will not make a split that is less than the block size, regardless of what you set the min split size to.  Here is the code that computes the split size.

```
protected long computeSplitSize(long goalSize, long minSize, long blockSize) {
  return Math.max(minSize, Math.min(goalSize, blockSize));
}
```

---

> **Q2:** If all the mappers above runs parallel on same node, do they run in different Threads with similar priority or a separate process at CPU level.

Each task runs in it's own [Java virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), so separate processes.

> **Q3:** if my num in conf.setNumMapTasks(int num) is greater than number of splits. That is say, I have num = 10 and the number of splits = 3. The total MR job that will be executed is 3.

The `setNumMapTasks()` is [not supported anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113819/setnummaptask-with-a-mapreduce-job) and was only meant as a hint to the MapReduce system.

> **Q4:** A mapper has to finish before the reducer starts - in all cases to my knowledge, any examples where it will not be. because the keys need sorting and handed them in order to reducers.
>
> Q5 so what is the effect of mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0.5. This would mean when the map task is 50% complete, start the reducers. but the reducer needs map jobs to be complete. correct???

Slow start involves copying the data to the appropriate machine.  The `reduce()` method in the reducer does not get invoked until all mappers are complete.

> what is the default number of reducers if I don't specify anything.

1

> so should I set conf.setNumReduceTasks(24)????

Whatever works best for your task.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I appreciate it. can you say what is goalsize and minsize above?

Comment: you mention each task run in seperate JVM? does it mean, if I have 50 mappers, I will create 50 JVM instances?

Comment: Goalsize is what the input format wants to use.  Minsize is the what you set the min split size to (or the default).

Comment: how does GoalSize determined? That is how does input Format knows what GoalSize to choose?

Comment: I didn't read that far into it, but it is probably determined base of on a number of factors such as file size and whether its compressed or not.

Comment: Thanks. is my understanding on second comment above correct?

Comment: I believe you are correct.  There may be some reuse of JVMs between tasks but I haven't actually researched that.